# Convert a database ID to a standard format of Alphabets

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a database called room and each room record has an incremental id and I am using this id as an identifier for people to join that room.

But I dont want the user to have id's like 50,51 etc so I was thinking to convert them to a more standard format (maybe 8 characters) and convert them into real id's while working with the db.

Do you guys have any suggestions on a simple implementation of this? I am using Python and GAE

Example: 51 maps to ATRGAGSA and 180 maps to ASTEHDQR etc. (by some kind of calculation)

Comment: But is 'ATRGAGSA' really more readable than 51?

Comment: How many rooms do you have at most?

Comment: Why not make the id a human-readable string (the name of the room) instead?

Comment: @Cameron Not really, but I mean incremental id's look weird especially i dont want people to guess id's and join rooms

@David I dint want the room names to be unique!

Comment: @Sunny: Well, if you don't want incremental IDs to look weird you could start off at a large number, or grow by 17 each time or something. If you don't want them guessable, use some sort of [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) or other randomly-generated identifier, but don't rely purely on security-through-obscurity to keep users out of rooms

Comment: @Cameron I see but I also am trying to make the id as smaller as possible. So I was thinking of using the character set and digit set to map id's to a sequence of alphabets and numbers... The problem with long integers is the user needs to type that in order to join the room...so you see the problem

Comment: @Sunny: If the user has to type in the IDs by hand, then surely the shortest, simplest IDs are best? You seem to want all the features of small numbers except the guessable part (and that they may look weird to users) :-)

Comment: @Sunny Your requirements of making the IDs both short and hard to guess are directly in conflict with each other!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) to produce a pseudorandom sequence of id numbers (instead of the incremental sequence), and convert them to strings using `base64.b32encode()`.